# Creating a session in PHP then checking for that session in JSP

Tags: php, jsp, session

I want to be able to create a session in PHP so that my JSP file can check for that session value and know that the PHP file was reached.

The idea is:

1. User goes to PHP file - session is created
2. The PHP file now redirects to a webapp
3. The web app notices the user isn't logged in and redirects to the JSP file for the user to log in.
4. The JSP will check if the PHP file was accessed by checking for the created session ID. If it was reached, it will auto-login for the user. If it wasn't reached, then we let the user log in.

Can this be done? If the PHP file redirects to the webapp which then redirects to the JSP, will the session still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cookies over sessions work just as well. This solved my problem.